# How measure the speed at which the video was played from youtube

Tags: android, video, youtube

I need create android app for testers. They need test internet speed on the SIM-card with different protocols and when play youtube video. I dont understand how measure internet speed when play video in youtube.

I tried use libraries for download video and measure downloaded video size before and after download. But this libraries not work([vget](https://github.com/axet/vget) and [wget](https://github.com/axet/wget) and [wget-android](https://github.com/pelya/wget-android))

I was looking for tools in Youtube API but not found it.

I not found information in stackoverflow and google.

But i think it possible. I want insert link for video from youtube and press start button. And after it i want see the speed at which the video was played